# Laravel 5 cache view/form inputs

Tags: forms, laravel, caching, input, view

I have weird problem with laravel 5. I have form with some jquery/ajax validation but sometimes inputs are cached after page reload and it's big issue.

Eg. I have hidden field so my ajax method know on which step is user and when user change step I set that input to 2 or 3 depends on current step with jquery, but after page reload if he was on step 3 it remain step 3 on that hidden field.

Important note it is totaly random not happening always it's pretty rare but happens and it should not.

So I need solution for preventing this cacheing not for current step evidention because it's just one of issues because of cacheing.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you need use: `<form autocomplete="off"` ...